# What architecture to use to imply 2 behaviours in one class?

Tags: c++, architecture

I am trying to make a class that will represent two different behaivours at the same time. Like the following:

```
class IMouse {
public:
    virtual void Walk() const = 0;
};

class TSimpleMouse : public IMouse {
public:
    void Walk() const;
};

class IBat {
public:
    virtual void Fly() const = 0;
};

class TSimpleBat : public IBat {
public:
    void Fly() const;
};

template <class TMouse, class TBat>
class TSuperCreatureImpl {
public:
    void Do() const {
        Walk();
        Fly();
    }
};

typedef TSuperCreatureImpl<TSimpleMouse, TSimpleBat> TSimpleSuperCreature;
```

This is important for me to have the behaviour by deafult (method Do), because I would like to make different typedefs. It seems to be very simple.

But I also would like methods Fly and Walk to have parameters (velocity, for example). How should I modify the architecture to have an opportunity to use many typedefs for different creatures?

How to change the architecture if there are no default constructors for Mouse and Bat?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class TMouse, class TBat>
class TSuperCreature : public TMouse, public TBat
{
  public:
    void do() const {
        this->walk();
        this->fly();
    }
};
```

> But I also would like methods Fly and Walk to have parameters (velocity, for example). How should I modify the architecture to have an opportunity to use many typedefs for different creatures? Thanks a lot.

You could give the functions default parameters...

```
virtual void Walk(double meters_per_second = 1.1) const = 0;
```

EDIT

> (from comment below) Imagine that we need 2 creatures: first one walks fast and flies slow, second one is the opposite. That means we have to write 2 typedefs. But I have no idea how to use velovity constants here. Which parts of architecture must have parameters?

One option is to do something like this:

```
template <class TMouse, class TBat, int walk_speed, int fly_speed>
class TSuperCreature : public TMouse, public TBat
{
  public:
    void do() const {
        this->walk(walk_speed);
        this->fly(fly_speed);
    }
};
```

If you want to use `double`s, they're not allowed as template arguments (at least not in C++03), but as a hack you could accept a pair of numbers and divide them inside the template, or more properly you could provide a policy class....

```
template <class TMouse, class TBat, class Speeds>
class TSuperCreature : public TMouse, public TBat
{
  public:
    void do() const {
        this->walk(Speeds::walk_speed);
        this->fly(Speeds::fly_speed);
    }
};

struct Speeds__Fly_Fast__Walk_Slow   // yes I know double underscores are reserved - I don't care!
{
    static const double walk_speed = 0.5; // m/s
    static const double fly_speed = 10;
};
```

Comment: Cool idea, thank you. But the architecture is not so flexible now... Cause I cannot create 2 different creatures (with different velicities, I mean)

Comment: You need `this->` to call the functions from the base classes. The calls have no arguments that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of the function must be available.

Comment: You can get around that by using a sentinel value (e.g. -1) to mean "whatever the default is for this creature" (which can be decided in the individual implementations) rather than having the default set in the base class.  Rather than hardcode a mysterious number, consider adding a constant called "Default_Velocity" or whatever.

Comment: Imagine that we need 2 creatures: first one walks fast and flies slow,  second one is the opposite. That means we have to write 2 typedefs. But I have no idea how to use velovity constants here. Which parts of architecture must have parameters? Thank you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! The idea to make a policy class is the best solution, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify.

Have a move interface that takes a method of movement as a aparameter;

```
enum MovementMethod { Walk, Fly, Swim };

class MoveInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void move(MovementMethod method) = 0;
};
// TMouse/TBat inheret from the MoveInterface

template <class TMouse, class TBat>
class TSuperCreatureImpl : public TMouse, public TBat
{
    public:
        virtual void move(MovementMethod /*method*/) 
        {
            TMouse::move(Walk);
            TBat::move(Fly);
        }
};
```

Comment: What happens when I call `TSuperCreatureImpl::move(Swim);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only in need of having one special behaviour at a time, i would apply the strategy pattern. Your Do-Method can then just call the current strategy, which is walk or fly.
You can have a CurrentBehaviour, which is selected when in need.

Furthermore i would think of a decorator, adding needed behaviour simply then when it is needed. i.e. you have a collection of behaviours and add a mouse AND a bat, when you need a supercreature. and when in need of a supercreature that can also bark, just add a dog behaviour.

Comment: I would like to give users of my classes an opportunity to create different creatures in a very simple way. Like this: 

typedef TSuperCreatureImpl<TSimpleMouse, TSimpleBat> TSimpleSuperCreature;

Can I do that and add some parameters for methods Walk etc? For example, avoid adding parameters to methods, but add them to classes.

Comment: you can completly remove the necessity for the user to add behaviours by encapsulating that in your creature class, e.g. having a constructor that gets Enums like suggested above and internally create all those behaviours selected by the user. loose coupling is very effective in the long run. you have a quite strong coupling when deriving like in the accepted answer.